# I am unable to call functions of one class in another class

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is my code . I am unable to call functons of google_charts class in my Demo class.  Help me fix the problem.

```
class google_charts:
    def all_files_to_one():
        pass

    prods = []
    srcs = []
    sname = []
    def process_compiled():
        global prods, srcs, sname
        sname.append('something')
        prods.append('something')
        srcs.append('something')

def demo():
    google_charts.all_files_to_one()
    google_charts.process_compiled()

demo()
```

The output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\demo.py", line 18, in <module>
    demo()
  File "C:\\demo.py", line 15, in demo
    google_charts.all_files_to_one()
TypeError: unbound method all_files_to_one() must be called with google_charts instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: Hacked question down to a visible problem with traceback.

Answer (score 4):

When defining a class in python, any methods within it must have 'self' as the first agrument:

```
class cheese(object):
       def some_method(self):
           return None
```

Comment: Technically, it only needs an extra argument, first, to represent the object instance. It is merely convention/best practice to use the name `self`.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Excellent point.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of all methods in your google_contacts class is incorrect. They must include the self parameter. Have a look at the documentation of Python classes:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

This may also be useful:

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use:

```
self.all_files_to_one()
```

Apart from that: the 'self' parameter is missing

This question is truly basic Python object-oriented programming.

Please read a Python tutorial first instead playing trial-and-error programming.

SO is not a replacement for reading basic documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of editing the original question removing the long, irrelevant code  to make the actual problem visible.  It looks like you've taken a bunch of functions and just wrapped a class around them.  In Python class methods need a self parameter.  The original functions were all of style `all_files_to_one` which had no state for a class to operate on.  One function did (`process_compiled`).  Here's a corrected version:

```
class google_charts(object):  # Python 2.X classes should derive from object

    # Initialize class instance state variables
    def __init__(self):
        self.prods = []  
        self.srcs = []
        self.sname = []

    # methods are called with the class instance object, traditionally named self
    def process_compiled(self):
        # Access instance variables via self
        self.sname.append('something')
        self.prods.append('something')
        self.srcs.append('something')

    # Use a static method when a method does not access class or instance state
    # but logically is associated with the class.  No self parameter is passed
    # for a static method.
    @staticmethod
    def all_files_to_one():
        print 'called all_files_to_one()'

def demo():
    gc = google_charts()  # instantiate an object
    gc.all_files_to_one() # call static method
    gc.process_compiled() # call instance method
    print gc.prods        # see some state in the instance

demo()
```

Output:

```
called all_files_to_one()
['something']
```

Please read a tutorial as the other posters have mentioned.